# Saving file path in PostgreSQL, removes backslashes

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin-4

The problem is the title. We have a postgreSQL database where we would like to save some paths and database removes backslashes( `\` ) from the path.

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.add_filenotification_array(IN fninput public.filenotification_input []) 
RETURNS Table(TYPE public."filenotification") AS 
$$
DECLARE
fn public.filenotification_input;
filenotification public.filenotification;
filenotificationlist public.filenotification [];
BEGIN
FOREACH fn IN ARRAY fninput LOOP
     INSERT INTO public."FileNotification"("FileLocation", "FileTargetLocation", "DocumentLanguage", "LastUpdate", "idStatus", "FileSize") 
 VALUES (fn.filelocation, fn.filetargetlocation, fn.documentlanguage, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 0, 0) 
 RETURNING "id", "FileLocation", "FileTargetLocation", "DocumentLanguage", "LastUpdate", "idStatus"
 INTO filenotification.id, filenotification.filelocation, filenotification.filetargetlocation, filenotification.documentlanguage, filenotification.lastupdate, filenotification.idstatus;
 filenotificationlist := array_append(filenotificationlist, filenotification);
END LOOP;
RETURN QUERY
 SELECT * FROM unnest(filenotificationlist::public.filenotification []);
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

File types:

```
TYPE filenotification AS (
  "id" integer,
  "filelocation" character varying,
  "filetargetlocation" character varying,
  "documentlanguage" character varying,
  "lastupdate" timestamp,
  "idstatus" integer
  );


TYPE filenotification_input AS (
  "filelocation" character varying,
  "filetargetlocation" character varying,
  "documentlanguage" character varying
);
```

From application we send a `java.sql.Array` of `filenotification`, with proper paths at `filelocation` and `filetargetlocation` parameters and the result is entirely without backlashes. Our question is: What is going on? Why does it remove backslashes?

Edit: if we put 4 backslashes into the function parameter then it outputs 1 backslash. If we put 8 backslashes into the function parameter then it outputs 2 backslash

Comment: It almost certainly isn't. Do you have any evidence to support your claim? Examples of what the values are on both the java and PostgreSQL side? Samples from the output of psql?

Comment: I dont understand your question. we put into database "C:\\Users\\kh\\Desktop\\workstuff\\samples\\test_in\\someBook.tif"
and we get "C:UserkhDesktopworkstuffsamplestest_insomeBook.tif"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok based on the dbfiddle I can see what the issue is. (BTW it doesn't like dollar quoting in there, that's why you can't run it. You just need to replace `$$` with `'` to quote it as a string, and it will run.)

Your input is `'{"(c:\\\\\\\rs\\me, Path, lang)"}'`. It's a an array of a type.

Let's take a simple type: `CREATE TYPE public.t AS (txt TEXT)`. When you select a type as a row, rather than with the fields expanded, any "special" characters will be escaped.

So: `SELECT ROW('C:\temp')::public.t` returns `("C:\\temp")`, and expanding it via `SELECT (ROW('C:\temp')::public.t).*` returns `C:\temp`.

Your input is a row (it uses the `(data1,data2,etc)` notation, which is a row literal, and unexpanded), therefore all backslashes are escaped. The path part of your expanded row (`SELECT ('(c:\\\\\\\rs\\me, Path, lang)'::public.filenotification_input).*`) would be `c:\\\rs\me`.

However there's one more level of escaping: the fact that the data is in an array. Same as with an unexpanded row, special characters will be escaped in an array. Running `SELECT ARRAY['C:\temp']` returns `["C:\\temp"]`.

Put them together, and you have backslashes needing escaping in your row, and each of those then needs escaping in the array. So to get a single backslash in "normal" text, you have to escape it in the row (`\\`) and then escape each of those in the array (`\\\\`).

So you need 4 backslashes in order to insert a single backslash into your table, given the way you supply your input.

Run this and have a look at the various outputs: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/83wBZsztETriNtZGDVXdcN/0

Comment: That would make sense, but the issue is that I tried the 4 backslashes directly into database. 
Example:
SELECT * FROM public.add_filenotification_array('{"(c:\\\\rs\\me, Path, lang)"}')
returns
156, c\rsme, Path, lang, 2019-03-15 14:29:22.343519, 0

Comment: @KristófHorváth Can you create an example in https://www.db-fiddle.com/ perhaps so I can see?

Comment: Added it to db-fiddle but it results in Schema errors.. The queries do work on my local database though. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g1RabAg82UaxxPHzyCNM6Y/1

Comment: @JSpratt Yeah, I also have a function for adding a single filenotification into database, which adds the backslashes as expected, but when I wrote this function (add_filenotification_array) Which takes in an array of type, it does not insert the backslashes, unless I put in 4 backslashes into the provided object property and even then it only puts in a single backslash...

Comment: @KristófHorváth See updated answer, I've figured out the issue.